# Why did the code not work after uploading the file to the hosting? It works on the local server

Tags: node.js

Why the code is not working after uploading the file to the hosting server?
It works on my local environment

here is my code:

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static('/public'));

app.get('', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {layout: 'layout'});
});

app.listen()
```

Got the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
/home/apka/apka/app.js:1
import express from 'express';
```

It worked with
`const express = require('express')`

but it doesn't work with:
`import express from 'express';`

Comment: In your package.json, what do you have for the `type:` key.  Do you have that key, and if so, what is the value?

Answer (score 1):

You should check that your local machine is identical to your development environment.
Have a look specifically on NodeJS version.

**import** statement is not available in all JavaScript/NodeJS versions

Comment: server version 18.9.1. i tried with .js as well as .mjs

Comment: By default  some Node versions use CommonJS modules, you can try putting {
  "type": "module"
} in your package.json

Comment: I tried but it didn't do anything

Comment: Did you compare Node version on local and production machine ?

Comment: Just now I checked the same versions on the local machine works but on the external server no longer